# Yii console commands stopped working on windows after updating from 2.0.3 to 2.0.4

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I just updated to Yii 2.0.4 and now my custom console command is not working. However, the default Hello still works.

```
$ yii hello
hello world
$ yii kw
Error: Unknown command "kw".
$ ls commands
HelloController.php  KWController.php
```

It was working immediately before in 2.0.3.

Strange because it shows up in `yii` command by itself:

```
$ yii | grep hello
- hello                        This command echoes the first argument that you have entered.
    hello/index (default)      This command echoes what you have entered as the message.
$ yii | grep kw
- kw
```

I am working on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is probably with the case of your controller name... the `kw` command would by default look for a `KwController.php` and won't find a `KWController.php` if your filesystem is case-sensitive.

You can fix that by either renaming the file, or if you don't want that, manually adding the controller file to the `controllerMap` in the `yii` file:

```
$application = new yii\console\Application($config);
$application->controllerMap['kw'] = 'console\controllers\KWController';
```

Comment: Yes that was it. I'm on Windows. I wonder why the Yii version would matter?

Comment: Windows file systems are not case sensitive so it indeed would've worked before. But there was recently [a commit done](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/commit/c01804d7c979ec1652229735ff015dda1db4909a) to be more strict about file name case. Went looking myself as I didn't know either. But there you go.